# How to get validation errors with expres-validator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express, express-validator

I have just started learning express-validator. I have read the docs of express-validator, but my question might have an answer in these docs which I didn't totally understand.
I want to check some values, but I don't know how to get the errors in case of the the values didn't match the validation.

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');
const router = require("express").Router();

router.post("/", (req, res, next)=>{
    // validate user input
    const username = req.body.username;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    check("username")
    .not().isEmpty().withMessage("Username must not be empty!");
    check("email")
    .not().isEmpty().withMessage("Email must not be empty!");
    check("password")
    .not().isEmpty().withMessage("Password must not be empty!");

    //Get check results
});
module.exports = router;
```

Also, does the `check()` return a promise or does it run synchronously?
And, in the docs there is:

```
app.post('/user', [
  check('username').isEmail()], (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  ...
  }
```

I have tried `validationResult(req)` but it gives me an object with some functions where only `isEmpty()` is `true` while the other functions are weather false, null, or undefined. And why is ther an array in the `post` method?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Example from the [docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/):

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');

app.post('/user', [
  // username must be an email
  check('username').isEmail(),
  // password must be at least 5 chars long
  check('password').isLength({ min: 5 })
], (req, res) => {
  // Finds the validation errors in this request and wraps them in an object with handy functions
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  User.create({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  }).then(user => res.json(user));
});
```

If you want your code to work, you have to follow the same structure.

If validationResult finds any errors, your server will response with this:

```
{
  "errors": [{
    "location": "body",
    "msg": "Invalid value",
    "param": "username"
  }]
}
```

In your case you can directly copy the code from this docs example and it will work fine.

Comment: But I don't understand why is there an array in the post method

Comment: If you want to know that, you'll have to ask that question to whoever maintains Express, it's just a decision they made.